# There is a small blue line between two of my buttons in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

That is an image of the two buttons with the small little blue line in the middle. This is my css/html

```html
<body>

  <div class="top">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="top-rectangle">

  </div>

  <div class="top-main">
    <p class="title3"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-buttons">
    <a href="/downloads/list.php" target="_blank">
      <button type="download-button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center">Download</button>
      <a href="pastes" target="_blank">
        <button type="purchase-button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center">Purchase</button>
      </a>
  </div>

  <style>
    .btnop {
      background: #298371;
      color: white;
      height: 104px;
      width: 308px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-width: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

I've looked for typing errors and stuff like that and I cannot find out why this little blue line is just sitting inbetween the buttons and attaching them..?

Comment: Links cannot contain interactive content such as buttons. The blue line is an underlined whitespace from your link. You’re not closing one of your `<a>` elements. Line-breaks between inline or inline-block elements cause whitespaces to appear. Also, `purchase-button` and `download-button` are not a valid button types. [Fix your HTML by validating it](https://html5.validator.nu/), and remove the line-breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Anchors, `<a>` elements should not contain buttons it's not valid syntax. As mentioned in the comments, the blue line is an underlined white space from the anchor. I'm guessing you are trying to redirect the user once they click on the `Download` or `Purchase` button, if that's the case, you can try styling the `anchors` per-se to look like buttons.

```css
a.btnop {
  background: #298371;
  color: white;
  line-height: 104px;
  width: 308px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <h1></h1>
</div>

<div class="top-rectangle">

</div>

<div class="top-main">
  <p class="title3"></p>
</div>

<div class="main-buttons">
  <a href="/downloads/list.php" target="_blank" class="btnop">Download</a>
  <a href="pastes" target="_blank" class="btnop">Purchase</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redirect the user using a button (or something that looks like a button), and you are trying to combine a with button, and it doesn't work. Try only using the a tag and style it such that it has a border, background color, and no underline, and it will look like a button.

Solution 2: you can get rid of your a tags and only use buttons, and put this in the button onclick function:

window.location = "https://www.something.com";

Answer (score 0):

the first reason is you simply missed the `</a>` closing tag for the first link

the second reason is you must change the `<a>` tag display to something not inline in order to give it the ability of containing something not text

simply add `display: inline-block` to `<a>` tags

```html
<body>

  <div class="top">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="top-rectangle">

  </div>

  <div class="top-main">
    <p class="title3"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-buttons">
    <a href="/downloads/list.php" target="_blank">
      <button type="download-button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center">Download</button>
    <!-- this is the missing closing tag --> </a>
    <a href="pastes" target="_blank">
      <button type="purchase-button" class="btnop" style="text-align: center">Purchase</button>
    </a>
  </div>

  <style>
    a {display: inline-block}
    .btnop {
      background: #298371;
      color: white;
      height: 104px;
      width: 308px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-width: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```